Как сравнить время забаненного участника в python?
у меня есть функция которая проверяет время забаненного участника полученного из бд
async def check_bans(user_id):
    current_time = datetime.now()
    end_time = cursor.execute('SELECT end_time FROM ban WHERE id = ?', (user_id,)).fetchone()[0]
    if end_time < current_time:
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM ban WHERE id', (user_id,))
        conn.commit()
        user = self.bot.get_user(user_id)
        await inter.guild.unban(user)

но в консоли выдается ошибка:
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Как можно проверить время чтоб функция работала корректно.
Структура бд:


Вы смогли перевести и понять текст сообщения об ошибке? "'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'"

поэтому то и спрашиваю, как можно сравнить?

Ну у вас в end_time строка, а в current_time у вас datetime. Приведите их к чему-то одному.

Перевести строку в datetime и сравнить ..

а код можете предоставить?

Почистите вопрос от всего лишнего, а потом просто поищите как делается перевод строки в датувремя - такие вопросы тут уже задавали.

end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

и сравнивай
